# Ajax request from jax-rs web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, tomcat, jax-rs

While sending a post request from my tomcat web service i got an error as below:
**" Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."**

I'm using tomcat 9.* and developed my web service with jax-rs java web api.

While i have tested my web service with postman, i got a good response from my web service (http 200 response). Yet, when i tried to send ajax post request i got the message above. I tried to enable the CORS filter and tried to send get request that working fine..

the web.xml:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class> 
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>'
```

the jax-rs post function:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/users2")    
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response SetAllTlcsStatus(List<TrafficLight> c){       
    System.out.println("You have entered the SetTlc function");
    return Response.ok() //200
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, 
    PUT")
            .allow("OPTIONS").build();
    }
```

the ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "http://localhost:8080/userManagement/rest/Traffic/users2",
    contentType :"application/json; charSet=UTF-8",
    data : d,
    dataType : "json",
    beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        console.log('Before');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(user, pass)); 
    }'
```

Answer (score 1):

You say "I tried to enable the CORS filter and tried to send **get** request that working fine."

Do you mean that GET method works but POST not? If so you must allow it on your REST service/terminal and also these settings 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")

Finally, if by any chance your AJAX still returns failed try

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "http://localhost:8080/userManagement/rest/Traffic/users2",
    contentType :"application/json; charSet=UTF-8",
    data : d,
    dataType : "json",
**xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
crossDomain: true,**
beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        console.log('Before');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth(user, pass)); 
    }'
```